# Should I escape the input parameters one by one or escape the sql query as a whole?

Tags: php, escaping, sql-injection

I am often escaping inputs one by one and I am wondering about the difference between two methods. Which one is a more common practice? I tried escaping the "escape requiring" fields first, then I end up writing long escaping code for each value. What are the disadvantages of escaping a whole sql sentence at once?

Comment: You cannot escape a whole SQL statement (if that's what you meant?) at once. It only works value-wise (and that value needs to be a string). Escaping can however be avoided by not using outdated database interface functions. (Please use search and look for PDO and bound parameters.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL / PDO / Prepared Statements - All a big jump, a bit overwhelming and a little confusing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061185/mysql-pdo-prepared-statements-all-a-big-jump-a-bit-overwhelming-and-a-lit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because inside the query you are using things like ' single quotes to indicate values and you don't want those escaped, but you do want to escape the values that might contain single quotes.

Comment: It's not a question of "accepting" - if you escape apostrophes that are required in the context of the MySQL syntax (i.e. delimiting strings) then that will entirely change your query, and most likely break it.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan its not that it doesn't accept escaped sql strings its that you don't want to escape the whole statement including values because a single quote is a control character to indicate the start and stop of a value.

Comment: yes I tried and It doesnt work. I didn't know because I didn't use it this way ever. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat offtopic but I feel it's very important.

This is not the first your question on the matter. And it seems you still don't get the point.

> are you sure mysql does not accept escaped sql strings?

I beg my pardon, but it seems this question being your main problem.
Instead of looking for understanding, instead of looking for explanation, you are just asking of some sort of positive answer.

The result of this question should be **the answer you gave to yourself,** based on your understanding of the matter.
Only in this case it will do any good for you.
Otherwise you will stumble on the very next step again.

Please, try to understand the meaning of escaping strings.
Your question makes absolutely no sense to anyone who has a very basic SQL knowledge.
Of course such whole query escaping will never work. Just because of the nature of the SQL query.
You desperately need **to understand** this nature. 
Please, read some books.
Please, ask for explanations, not for some assurance.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements and use bind parameters.  Anything else is a hack waiting to happen

Comment: Not so true. Using prepared statements and bind parameters as a some sort of magic chant, without understanding it, is a hack waiting as well. Yet escaping is still unbreakable if used with sense.

Comment: @Shrapnel Could you elaborate that? For educational purposes.

Comment: As long as you can treat all your data as strings and thus escape and quote it, thre is no "hack waiting" as well. "Anything else" is good enough no less than prepared statement. On the other hand, once you have to insert an identifier, no escaping|quoting, nor prepared statements would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Escape each inputs one by one. If you will do this for the whole SQL query, you cannot be sure that SQL statement is still valid after escaping. Let's say instead of

```
aaa
```

user will type in

```
a", "a
```

so in the generated SQL you will receive

```
("a", "a")
```

instead of

```
("aaa")
```

I think that escaping whole SQL statement will not work in such situation.

Answer (score -1):

I guess escaping the sql string is more advantageous using mysql_real_escape_string. In reference to time and memory. Some validations can be done at each input level if needed.

Comment: Dude, this is not your only answer making absolutely no sense. May be you need to learn a bit more before trying to help others?

Comment: Sure sir, I try to help and learn. I am trying to get where you are

Answer (score -1):

You are worried about long code for escaping each var but for some reason you forgot the purpose of a function.

```
function escape_me($value) {
     $value = strip_tags($value);
     $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
     .........
}

$var1 = escape_me($_POST['var1']);
```

Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @Uğur having such a function as a grave mistake.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Why would escaping inputs be a bad thing?  That's just an example.

Comment: combining different escaping techniques is a bad thing. there are many questions on SO explaining that.