# MYSQL optimization and design rules: PHP method vs MYSQL procedure on local host

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I don't know if this is a dumb question but I have this two doubts maybe you can help me clear out:

If my database and web server are on the same host, is there any relevant benefit on putting my procedures for conditionally selecting (using more than one SQL query) elements from a table in a SQL database procedure instead of just implementing them in a webserver-side script (in my case PHP) method with the rest of the web application code?

Secondly, and maybe even more important: Am I breaking any design rules doing / not doing this?

More specifically, I made a PHP script to select a random row from a table according to a probability density function determined by the number of previous selections of each row, which goes like this:

```
function acceptation_rejection_method($link,$tablename,$column,$condition="")
{
    $max=get_col("max(".$column.")",$tablename,$link,$condition);
    $min=get_col("min(".$column.")",$tablename,$link,$condition);
    $bar_value=mt_rand($min,$max);

    $count=get_nelements($tablename, $link,"where ".$column."<=".$bar_value);
    $selected_row=get_row(mt_rand(0,$count-1), $tablename, $link,"where "
    .$column."<=".$bar_value);
    return $selected_row;
}
```

My function implements the acceptance rejection method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance-rejection_method), and my question is: Taking on account that my database and my web server are on the same host, is it of any improvement to rewrite that script as SQL code returning the row? (Assuming that all users of my app are using it constantly, like almost once in every request)

Comment: it seems you don't sanitize your $column, $table and other variables -  it is a breaking some design rules for sure

Comment: symcbean is right, you are talking of the model exclusively here

Comment: MVC mention removed by popular claim, sanitization is performed in get_nelements, get_row and get_col before calling mysql_query, though maybe I should check $count and also $min and $max values before getting $bar_value. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: ummm.. what kind of santitization - may I ask?

Comment: since it's something of an internal function I just make a standard check to aknowledge variables have valid values and conform a valid query to the set of tables I'm working with. Am I missing anything in particular?

Comment: nothing particular. I just wanted to make a note that "standard" way of sanitizing SQL variables - escaping them- is quite useless either for the numbers and identifiers

Comment: You're right, and that's been a real bummer since I started this project... Probably my next query to the community will be how to improve my sanitization skills or if there's any set of more powerful tools I'm not aware of to help me with the process, I sure should start digging into that a little deeper...

Comment: Well, I hope that following my answer will answer some of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8061617/285587

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only your answers are making me aware of the probable issues when treating every input as a string but also yesterday I read about PDO and I'm preparing to work with it, so it's good to get some advice on how to properly use it. I guess next step is read about XSS since I don't know the first thing about this hacking techniques and how they should influence my coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to know whether you should encode your acceptance/rejection algorithm into a pure database function, or whether what you're doing here is "right", from both an architectural and a performance point of view.

From a performance point of view, if there were a way to represent the query as a single SQL statement, it would likely be faster than your current implementation, but (assuming the column is indexed), probably not all that much faster.

You could, of course, create a stored procedure - but it looks like you're running this on multiple tables and columns, so you'd end up with lots of stored procedures.

Stored procedures have benefits and drawbacks, but in this case I'd say they make the application more fragile. Again, I doubt whether you'd see a huge performance impact.

Architecturally, I think what you're doing is likely the cleanest solution - you're abstracting the algorithm behind a single method.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, my knowledge of SQL procedures and SQL in general is quite limited and I'm not aware of when a stored procedure approach is the smartest solution (nevertheless I'm working that angle too just to learn a little more about them and see where it takes me, just wanted to know which solution is better in general and for my case and you answered that quite clearly).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the *form* of requesting the same data from the same source does matter anything.

> Assuming that all users of my app are using it constantly, like almost once in every request

<s>Then you may want to think of the changing the approach.</s>

Sorry, I am contradicts with myself.

**First of all you have to profile your code and see, if it makes any trouble.**

Only if so, then you may want to think of the changing the approach.

Say, you can request all the numbers at once, randomize them and store in the memory cache. and then just request one by one, deleting after use. refresh on exhaust.

Comment: Well, it actually doesn't make much of a trouble, just wanted to know if it's appropiate or not. Making all requests at once it's not usefull in this scenario for sure I'll take that advice and apply it to another case I'm working with right now.

Answer (score 1):

> In a simple MVC architecture design where database and web server are on the same host

Eh? MVC is a design pattern not a system/service architecture.

> is there any relevant benefit on putting my procedures for conditionally selecting (using more than one SQL query) elements from a table in a SQL database procedure instead of just implementing them in a webserver-side script

Firstly, for the same population, you shouldn't need "more than one SQL query" regardless if you are looking at the entire sample or just a subset. i.e. your algorithm is flawed regardless of how you implement it.

Secondly, using the script you are hauling large amounts of data between the database and the PHP script which is an overhead. You are processing large amounts of data in PHP. PHP is not explicitly designed form manipulating large data sets - SQL and PL/SQL are. If you do as much processing as is practical on the database, then your application should run faster with less code.

Comment: Ok, then change that first line for "In a simple MVC design pattern design..." (Sorry,it's not an excuse,but English is not my native language, hence the trouble) Actually, using the script I make 4 querys, 3 of them return one number and the other the selected row, so the "large" amount of data php has to deal with is 3 numbers (am I right?), and the actual overhead is that of 3 requests and 3 really short answers. Not not sure if it's that much of an efficiency hole, but anyway, something to beconsidered for the most general case of manipulating querys outputting large amounts of data, sure.