# MySQL injection prevention not working?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I want to prevent the 1=1 using the mysql_real_escape_string but not sure if im doing it right because I can still perform 1=1. This is my code:

```
$memberId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["memberId"]);
$sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, dateSent, message, messageId FROM member, message WHERE member.memberId = message.sentFromId AND message.inboxId=" . $memberId . " ORDER BY dateSent DESC;";
```

Thanks

Comment: I've explained the whole matter in [MySQL / PDO / Prepared Statements - All a big jump, a bit overwhelming and a little confusing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061185/mysql-pdo-prepared-statements-all-a-big-jump-a-bit-overwhelming-and-a-lit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_**STRING**() is for **STRINGS**, not integers. There's nothing in `1=1` that requires escaping, so m_r_e_s() will pass it back unchanged.

if you're dealing with integers, then use integer tools:

```
$memberID = intval($_GET['memberId']);
```

Answer (score 3):

The only correct way to not have SQL injections is using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).
If you attempt to mitigate using escaping you will fail. 
If you as a rule never concatenate your queries and always use prepared statements, you have a chance.
It also has the advantage of making your code more readable.
And has no disadvantages.

Comment: +1 I agree with MK. but (just to share) my stand on `prepared statements` is with `PDO` and not `mysqli` :)

Comment: Re. 'no disadvanteges': How do you create a multirow insert (a.k.a extended insert) using prepared statements?

Comment: this is not true. if you treat all your data as strings *as a rule*, you will never fail, save for the LIMIT clause parameters. And prepared statements still not a silver bullet anyway. It won't help for identifiers

Comment: @Mchl looks like you are right.  Other implementations (e.g. JDBC) have a concept of batch prepared statements, but not PHP, apparently.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I totally do not understand what you just said.

Comment: ok, in other words. 1. prepared statements is not the only correct way to not have SQL injections. Nothing inherently wrong in in quoting/escaping - it's good if used as a rule as well. 2. sometimes we cannot avoid concatenating and prepared statements won't help us. So it isn't an ideal solution either

Comment: @mk: prepared statements can only have placeholders for VALUES. if your DB design requires field/table names be inserted dynamically, you can't use a prepared statement. `SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ?=?` is not possible, only `SELECT x FROM y WHERE z=?`.

Comment: @MarcB yes, of course, but that's a totally different problem and conversation.  And then the ids will never be coming in as user inputs, most likely.

Comment: @MK: I don't know what JDBC does, but it surely is not using any MySQL-native mechanism for that. There simply is no MySQL syntax for multirow prepared inserts (except for creating a statement with specific number of rows, which is kind of ugly)