# How to use array from one function, inside another function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to the world of OOP and PDO and just need a bit of a hand when returning data in one function and wanting to use that inside another function.

Below is my function to get all gecko data from my database, at the moment i have it printing out the array so i know it's working.

function getGecko:

```
public function getGecko($geckoName){
    $dbh = $this->dbh;
    try {
        if (!$geckoName) {
            throw new Exception("No gecko name set!");
        }
        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM geckos WHERE gecko_name = '$geckoName'");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
        $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();  
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if($row_count > 0){
            print_r($row);
            return true;
        } else {
            echo 'No information found for '.$geckoName.'!';
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

which outputs as - `Array ( [gecko_id] => 1 [gecko_name] => Zilly [gecko_aquisition_date] => 0000-00-00 [gecko_type] => Normal [gecko_gender] => Male [gecko_traits] => [gecko_bio] => Hench bastard [gecko_health_check] => All good! [gecko_bred] => 0 [gecko_hatchling] => 0 [gecko_clutch] => [gecko_photo] => )` - no problem.

But i want to use that data inside a function called getMorph to utilise  `[gecko_type] => Normal`. I have tried things like:

```
public function getMorph($geckoName){
    $this->getGecko($geckoName);
    echo $row['gecko_type'];
}
```

But it returns nothing at all. I am quite used to php in the procedural sense, i'm just trying to better myself and my code and wanted to get stuck into OOP. I do apologise if this is considered a 'noob' question but as i say, i am trying to learn.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: where is $row defined in getMorph? should you return something to a variable? $this->getGecko($geckoName); returns true but is never given to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first function is that you're returning a boolean value. No actual data is returned. Also, in the `getMorph()` function, you're trying to use the `$row` variable. This won't work as the `$row` variable only exists inside the local scope of the function `getGecko()`. This would actually cause PHP to print an error message. Had you enabled [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393), you'd have found this out.

To fix the issue, you can modify your first function to **return** the array:

```
    if($row_count > 0){
        // print_r($row);
        return $row;
    } else {
        echo 'No information found for '.$geckoName.'!';
        return false;
    }
```

Then, in your second function, you can access the array like so:

```
public function getMorph($geckoName){

    // $morph now contains the entire array 
    // returned by the other function
    $row = $this->getGecko($geckoName);

    // output the array contents
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($row, TRUE), '</pre>';

    // return the specific gecko_type value
    return $row['gecko_type'];
}
```

I suggest you read up on [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). It's going to be very useful. Also, completely unrelated the issue above, you're directly inserting the user input in your SQL query. **Don't do that!** Use parameterized queries instead - that way, you'll be able to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

The following questions has more details on the subject:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [How does PHP PDO's prepared statements prevent sql injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718942/)

Comment: This gives me all this (from the dump) array(12) { ["gecko_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["gecko_name"]=> string(5) "Zilly" ["gecko_aquisition_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["gecko_type"]=> string(6) "Normal" ["gecko_gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["gecko_traits"]=> NULL ["gecko_bio"]=> string(13) "Hench bastard" ["gecko_health_check"]=> string(9) "All good!" ["gecko_bred"]=> string(1) "0" ["gecko_hatchling"]=> string(1) "0" ["gecko_clutch"]=> NULL ["gecko_photo"]=> NULL }

Comment: However when commenting out the dump, it returns a blank page

Comment: @AndyHolmes: Yes. How do you initialize the object and call the method?

Comment: @AndyHolmes: **First step**: Add [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) to the very top of your script.

Comment: I have mate, made no difference at the time as there was nothing wrong, i just popped the wrong word in for my return. It's fine now :)

Comment: Thanks for your added notes friend, i already know about SQL Injection, i use prepared statements with MySQLi. This is just local at the moment and prepared statements weren't needed straight away for my functions to work. Will be updating it all soon though :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes: Great. I hope it helps a future visitor reading this question. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Your function `getGecko` returns only a Boolean and `$row` is only a local variable in that method. So you can either change the return value to return the actual data or you can create a private variable in your PHP Class.

For changing the return type, you could in `getGecko` change that return to something like this:

```
if($row_count > 0){
    // ...
    return $row;
}
```

And then in your `getMorph` function do something like:

```
public function getMorph($geckoName){
    $row = $this->getGecko($geckoName);
    echo $row['gecko_type'];
}
```