# How to i prevent sql injection from this code , please add your suggestions in my code

Tags: php, mysql

```
  <?php
// I fetching data from sql table "product".i want to prevent all unwanted characters and all.please add your suggestions in my code.  

  if(isset($_GET['search'])){

   $search_query = $_GET['user_query'];

   $get_pro = "select * from product where title like '%$search_query%'";

   $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

   while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
   $pro_title = $row_pro['title'];
    echo " <span>$pro_title</span> "
   }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Badly formatted question is hard to read: unlikely to get a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent SQL Injection PDO(PHP Data Objects) is the best way to go. PDO gives more flexibilty to the programmer as if you want to switch your project to use another database, PDO makes the process very easy. You only have to change the connection string and a few queries.
If your project is in initial stage and you want to attain more flexibility I'll highly recommend to switch over to PDO. To know more about PDO you can refer to this link [How does PHP PDO's prepared statements prevent sql injection? What are other benefits of using PDO? Does using PDO reduce efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719103/6352772)

Okay coming back to the problem you asked. To prevent SQL injection in mysqli interface you could use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function which takes two args:

1. connection- Specifies the MySQL connection to use(required)
2. escapestring- The string to be escaped(required)

After this step your code will look like this-

```
 $search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['user_query']);
```

where $conn will be your connection handle.
You can append the '%' operator after this step and can use the result to perform the query.

Comment: thanks for your great suggestion.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please don't forget to upvote it.

Comment: Mysqli is perfectly fine, and you forgot to mention the only proper way of preventing sql-injection, which is using parameterized queries with placeholders.

Comment: As Qirel says here, doing manual escaping is how you end up with SQL injection bugs because you'll have to compose your query using string interpolation or concatenation. Either way you're at risk if you make even a single mistake. Placeholder values *guarantee* you're doing it right if you're absolutely disciplined about using them every time you're injecting user data into your query.