# nl2br() not working with my textarea

Tags: php

Can somebody please help me with this problem.

I'm simply trying to display a message from users. The message comes to my database from a  textarea. My problem is when I am typing message and formatting it with breaking into paragraphs it is not display in that format and display it as a one long paragraph.

like this.

> To change the overall look of your document, choose new Theme elements
>   on the Page Layout tab. To change the looks available in the Quick
>   Style gallery, use the Change Current Quick Style Set command.
>   \r\n\r\nBoth the Themes gallery and the Quick Styles gallery provide
>   reset commands so that you can always restore the look of your
>   document to the original contained in your current template.

I tried with nl2br() and strip_tags() but still no luck

The Code from validation message.

```
// Check for message
if ( !empty ( $_POST['message'])) {
    if ( mb_strlen ( $_POST['message'], 'UTF-8') <= 20 ) {
        $reg_errors['message'] = 'Your message must be greater than 20 characters';
    } else {
        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['message']);
    }   
} else {
    $reg_errors['message'] = 'Message: This field is required.';
}
```

This is the code I use when select message from db

```
$message= $row['message'];
$message= nl2br(strip_tags($message));
```

when echoing $message it print a paragraph like above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14786251/285587

Comment: as you said with that answer I think I used nl2br() and mysqli_real_escape_string() correctly here. Inst it?

Comment: problem is still not sloved. these \r\n\r\n characters not convert to <br /> tag with my code.

Comment: Did you try outputting the character length of the message back to the browser (from PHP, as a response) so that you could see what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing excessive escaping when adding data into database.
If you are using prepared statements, just remove  mysqli_real_escape_string() call from your code.
Otherwise you are doing it twice - som you have to find the place where it happens and remove extra mysqli_real_escape_string() call from your code.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, by using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` you are making it escape the backslashes so at the time of transaction for example `\r\n` becomes `\\r\\n`, however, if those have already been escaped by Javascript then what you end up during transaction is `\\\\r\\\\n` which translates back into html as

1. a literal backward slash
2. r
3. a literal backward slash
4. n

So you might want to replace them with appropriate characters before adding into your database. Doing that you can pic from a variety of built-in functions such as [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)…