# PHP : How to Prevent Sql Injection For this Code

Tags: php, mysql

I am New to development.I have created an simple html 5 game for facebook .I use post Request to `update.php` to store score in database.

Below is my code

```
<? 
include 'config.php';
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$score = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['score']);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "UPDATE heli SET score = '$score' WHERE app = '$id'";
echo $query;
$result=mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Many Complain that my code is vulnerable to Sql injection.Any one Suggest good code that is Secure.Thanks..

Comment: That code looks okay from here security-wise.

Comment: Please, stop reposting the same question...

Comment: `mysql` extension is *deprecated*. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: You are using ´mysql_real_escape_string´, so your code should be safe against SQL-injections. But you should consider moving to ´MySQLi´ or ´PDO´, as ´MySQL´ is deprecated.

Comment: @Tjoene not totally. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: @JW. Thanks for the link. Didn't know what.

Comment: -6 :o OMG i must improve my questioning skills :)

Comment: +1 Nothing wrong with questioning skills.

Comment: Thanks alot guys for +3 :) humanity Restored :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your current code is not vulnerable. However your other code can be.
As long as you're taking `mysql_real_escape_string()` as a sort of "universal injection preventor", you are in danger.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8061617/285587) with *explanations* I gave to similar question

Answer (score 4):

use `PDO` or `MySQLi` Extension on `PHP`. Please read the article below,

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [SQL injection that gets around **mysql_real_escape_string()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)